# jqgrid saveRow on a row in edit mode fails when another row is going into edit mode

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the row editing facility in jqGrid to do inline editing, and then saving the data in the grid (i.e., using "clientArray" for the url).  I am using the "onSelectRow" function to put the select row into edit mode.

This logic works fine when the row is saved via a save button, but when another row is clicked while the first row is still in edit mode, calling the saveRow function for the first row does not save the changes, and the row fields revert to their prior values.

I have tried this both with and without the "beforeSelectRow" function.  How can I properly save row changes in this context?

Here is the logic:

```
var iRow;

...

beforeSelectRow: function (id, e) {
    if (id != null) {
        if (iRow != null && iRow != id) {
            SaveRow();
        }
    }
    return true;
},

onSelectRow: function (id, status, e) {
    if (id != null) {
        if (iRow != null && iRow != id) {
            SaveRow();
        }
        if (iRow == null) {
            iRow = id;
            $("#GridMain").jqGrid("editRow", id, false);
            $("#RowPanel").show();
        }
    }
}

function SaveRow() {
    // Save the current row if it was being edited
    if (iRow != null) {
        $("#GridMain").jqGrid("saveRow", iRow, { url: "clientArray" });
        $("#RowPanel").hide();
        iRow = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check a couple of things:

1. Check the iRow is correct. If the row that needs to be saved is still editable when SaveRow is called, you should be able to get the row id by calling the following without the need of keeping a global variable:
   iRow = $('tr[aria-selected=true]', $("#GridMain")).attr('id');  // Do you have the correct id?
2. If your using client side sorting, check that you have at least one column set as key on your column model. For example, if you have a hidden Id column it should be set up like this:
   {name: 'Id', index: 'Id', label: 'Id', editable: false, hidden: true, key: true }

Also, from what I see on your code you are using a "#RowPanel" row to edit the values? If so probably you need to send the edited values back to the grid on Save then. Otherwise you shouldn't need to show and hide anything when editing and saving.

Hope this helps!